# Мигающий текст GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, графика, текст, glut

Здравствуйте, Я не могу сделать мигающий текст в glut.
Вот код:

```
// graphic.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.

void Initialize();
void DrawField();
void timer(int = 0) {
  DrawField();
  glutTimerFunc(1000, timer, 0);
  glutSwapBuffers();
}

void drawText(const char* text, int length, int x, int y) {
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  double* matrix = new double[16];
  glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, matrix);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0, 400, 0, 400, -5, 5);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glPushMatrix();
  glLoadIdentity();
  glRasterPos2i(x, y);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, (int) text[i]);
  }
  glPopMatrix();
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadMatrixd(matrix);
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);      //Указываем размер окна
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);  //Позиция окна
  glutCreateWindow("test");          //Имя окна
  Initialize();                      //Вызов функции Initialize
  glutDisplayFunc(DrawField);  //Вызов функции отрисовки
  timer();
  glutMainLoop();
  _getch();
  return 0;
}

void Initialize() {
  //Выбрать фоновый (очищающий) цвет
  glClearColor(0.1, 0.0, 0.3, 1.0);

  //Установить проекцию
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(5.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
void DrawField()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  drawText("Sample Text", 11, 40, 50);
}
```

Как можно сделать мигающий текст?

Answer (score 1):

Начать можно с того, что в зависимости от времени или номера кадра вы рисуете или НЕ рисуете ваш текст. При этом заливку цветом фона (`glClear`) делаете всегда. Например, на кадрах от 0 до 30 ваш текст будет видно, а на кадрах от 30 до 60 - нет. Аналогично можно привязаться ко времени. Эти проверки я бы добавил в функцию `DrawField`.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала можете попробовать так переделать метод:

```
void DrawField()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  static int i = 0;
  i++;
  if (i % 30 > 15)
  {
    drawText("Sample Text", 11, 40, 50);
  }
}
```